# Replace shortcode in SQL database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying replace this shortcode

`[RICH_REVIEWS_SHOW category=”all” num=”6″]`

with this shortcode

`[site_reviews summary count="3" hide="date"]` in a wordpress database.

I've tried the plugin **"better search and replace"** but no luck.

I've also tried using this code via the cpanel.

```
update wplq_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content,'[RICH_REVIEWS_SHOW category=”all” num=”6″]','[site_reviews summary count="3" hide="date"]');
```

Initially no matches, if I remove certain parts of the shortcode I get some results. I'm a bit lost as to what will get the job the job done.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL in your example is correct.

A likely explanation for the issue is that the double-quotes within the `[RICH_REVIEWS_SHOW category=”all” num=”6″]` do not match the double quotes used within the shortcode stored in the `post_content` table.

For example `”` vs `″` vs `"`

I suggest finding a post manually that has this shortcode and copying that that shortcode into the SQL query. Then try again.

Comment: Thank you very much that has worked. I went in to the wp_posts table and copied the shortcode directly from a post_content.

Comment: Glad to hear that @user12185154, can you please flag the answer as resolved please?